# vsftpd: allow access only for certain users

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I want to setup FTP server to allow only certain users, so with vsftpd, I add in `vsftpd.conf`:

```
local_enable=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
```

In `/etc/vsftpd_user_conf` for the unix user `foo` I set in a file foo:

```
local_root=/home/foo/ftpdir
anon_world_readable_only=NO
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
local_umask=022
```

... and I launch vsftpd. I can login to FTP with user foo. However, I also can with other unix users! How can I disable other unix users?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> In vsftpd.conf add:
>   `userlist_enable=YES`
>   `userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist`
>   `userlist_deny=NO`

Edit the file to contain a username per row.

Comment: Worked for me too thanks. Worth noting that a userlist file already exists at /etc/vsftpd/user_list. However by default its in deny mode by userlist_deny=YES. So if you set userlist_deny=NO without either setting a new userlist_file or replacing the deny list in /etc/vsftpd/user_list with an accept list then you will have compromised your server security.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: @ekerner * user list config location is not at /etc/vsftpd/user_list, but at /etc/vsftpd.user_list

Answer (score 4):

there is a file in /etc/ftpusers put the allowed one only here.

no need to define in vsftpd

Comment: Didn't you got that one backwards? "list of users disallowed FTP access"

Answer (score 0):

add the user you want to deny to  user_list list.